# ACTION_GET_CONTENT Orientation Incorrect When Selecting From Recent

Tags: android, android-intent, orientation, android-gallery

I have code for the user to select gallery photos using `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, however the orientation differs if the user selects from Recent or Gallery. I have created the intent:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, Globals.UPLOAD_PHOTO_EXISTING);
```

Within the `onActivityResult`, I use the following code to determine the orientation of the image:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

String[] orientationColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, orientationColumn, null, null, null);

int orientation = -1;
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
    orientation = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(orientationColumn[0]));
}
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "orientation = " + orientation);
matrix.postRotate(orientation);
```

When I select the image from Gallery, I get the correct orientation of 270, but when I select the same image from Recent, the orientation calculated is 0. Why would there be a difference between the Gallery and Recent?

**UPDATE**

Here are the choices I have when using the `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. The Recent option does bring up the images stored locally on my phone. Why would the `Uri` be different if I choose the exact same photo from Recent or Gallery?

[image]

Comment: I don't know what "Recent" is. However, you are assuming that every `Uri` returned by an `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` request is known to `MediaStore`, which is incorrect.

Comment: I've added a little more on my explanation. It's the same photo if I choose from Recent or Gallery, so why would the `Uri` be any different?

Comment: There is no requirement that the `Uri` be the same, or that either `Uri` be one from `MediaStore`. The same would hold true if the user chose from Dropbox, Google Drive, or any of your other options. If *you* work with `MediaStore` directly, you know that `MediaStore` knows about the stuff.